# How can a gradle build handle both antlr3 and antlr4 grammars?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, antlr4, antlr3

I have got a legacy project in which both ANTLR3 and ANTLR4 grammars are used. We want to update the `ant` build system to `gradle`. There is a [antlr plugin for gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/antlr_plugin.html) that supports ANTLR2/3/4. However, apparently it supports only one of the three at a time (depending on the added dependencies).

In our project, antlr3 files have suffix `.g` while antlr4 grammars are suffixed `.g4`.

Is there an option to the plugin or an alternative plugin which allows me to use grammars of both ANTLR versions at a time?

Thanks for any hint.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'antlr'
}

dependencies {
    // ...

    // If both are mentioned, then "X.g" is also treated as antlr4
    antlr "org.antlr:antlr:3.5.2" // use ANTLR version 3
    antlr "org.antlr:antlr4:4.5" // use ANTLR version 4
}
```

Comment: As a last resort, you can always [run Ant from Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html). I use Maven but actually build ANTLR3 through Ant plugin because not all needed configuration is accessible through ANTLR Maven plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the antlr plugin does not support multiple versions. A workaround is to use `JavaExec` tasks to call antlr3 or antlr4. Here is a way how to do it.

1. Create configurations for using gradle dependency management for retrieving antlr3 or antlr4.

```
configurations{
  antlr3,
  antlr4
}

dependencies {
    antlr3 "org.antlr:antlr:3.5.2"
    antlr4 "org.antlr:antlr4:4.7.1" 

    compile "org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5.2"
    compile "org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.7.1" 
}
```

2. Define the tasks.

```
task runAntlr4(type:JavaExec) {
   //see incremental task api, prevents rerun if nothing has changed.
   inputs.dir "src/main/antlr4/"
   outputs.dir "$projectDir/build/generated/antlr/main/"

   classpath = configurations.antlr4

   main = "org.antlr.v4.Tool" 

   args = [ "-verbose", "-visitor", 
            "-o",  "$projectDir/build/generated/antlr/main/",  
            "-package", <my-package>,
            "src/main/antlr4/MyLanguage.g4"]
}

compileJava.dependsOn runAntlr4
```

- Analog for `antlr3` with `configurations.antlr3` and "org.antlr.Tool".
- Add the output directory to `sourceSets.main.java`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work any longer in newer gradle versions as main is now final and cannot be overriden any longer. Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: For me this still works with newer Gradle version. Also the documentation also overrides main attribute, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html

Comment: We had it wrapped in a plugin. That did not work. Now it works. Just one thing, inputs.dir is now a method e.g. must be now inputs.dir(...)